# Cambiar lenguaje de month_year_picker en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Se me presentó este inconveniente para cambiar el idioma del control *month_year_picker*. Este es mi código:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:month_year_picker/month_year_picker.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';
import 'package:worker_attendance/services/auth_service.dart';
import 'package:worker_attendance/services/db_service.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';

   
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AuthService()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => DbService()),
          ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => AttendanceService()),

        ],

      child: MaterialApp(
        
        localizationsDelegates: [
          GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
          GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
        ],
        supportedLocales: [
          const Locale('es')
        ],
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          title: 'Asistencia de Operarios',
          theme: ThemeData(
            primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          ),


          home: const SplashScreen(),),


    );
  }
}
```

Aqui hago el llamado:

```
Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Text(
              attendanceService.attendanceHistoryMonth,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
            ),
            OutlinedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final selectedDate =
                  await showMonthYearPicker( locale: const Locale("es", "Es"),
                      context: context,initialDate: DateTime.now(),firstDate: DateTime(2019),lastDate:DateTime.now());
                  String pickedMonth =
                  DateFormat('MMMM yyyy').format(selectedDate!);
                  attendanceService.attendanceHistoryMonth = pickedMonth;

                },
                child: const Text("Seleccionar mes")),
          ],
        ),
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: No MonthYearPickerLocalizations found.
> E/flutter (24868): CalenderScreen widgets require MonthYearPickerLocalizations to be provided by a Localizations widget ancestor.

Comment: Es "ES", no "Es"... Es [sensible a mayúsculas](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Locale/Locale.html). ¡Nunca olvides revisar la documentación!

Answer (score 1):

solo déjalo con el "es" y listo
reemplaza esto que tienes: supportedLocales: [const Locale('es')],

Por esto: supportedLocales: const [Locale('es', '')],

y utiliza esto en tu onPressed:

onPressed: () async {

```
    DateTime? pickedDate = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,

      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(1920),
      lastDate: DateTime(2500),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
              primary: AppColors.oscureColor,
            ),

            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: ButtonStyle(
                foregroundColor:
                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(AppColors.colorAcento),
              ),
            ),

            textTheme: ThemeData.light().textTheme.copyWith(
                  titleLarge: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontFamily: "MonB",
                  ),
                ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );

    if (pickedDate != null) {
      final DateFormat formatter = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
      String formattedDate = formatter.format(pickedDate);

      setState(() {
        _birthController.text = formattedDate;
      });
    }
  },
```

sino te funciona y utilizas el paquete intl agrega esto en el main
Intl.defaultLocale = 'es';

Answer (score 0):

prueba solo dejando en el local del showMonthPicker const Locale("es"),solo con el "es". ya que en supportedLocales, tienes es "es" que es para español, por lo que entiendo ese solo es suficiente, y el "ES" pues esta de más y no esta definido.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: En realidad, el _countryCode_ (el segundo parámetro) es [opcional](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Locale/Locale.html), y además **es sensible a mayúsculas**. [Sí está definido](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/cldr-aux/charts/28/summary/es.html#528).

Comment: comprendo, muchas gracias por la aclaración.